# Vue: All components rerender upon unrelated data property change only if a prop comes from a method that returns an object or array

Tags: vue.js, rerender, vue-props

(Vue 3, options API)

The **problem**: Components rerender when they shouldn't.

The **situation**:

1. Components are called with a prop whose value comes from a method.
2. The method cannot be replaced with a computed property because we must make operations on the specific item (in a v-for) that will send the value processed for that component.
3. The method returns an Array. If it returned a primitive such as a String, components wouldn't rerender.

To **reproduce**: change any parent's data property unrelated to the components (such as `showMenu` in the example below).

Parent

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="menu">
      <div @click="showMenu = !showMenu">Click Me</div>
      <div v-if="showMenu">
        Open Console: A change in a property shouldn't rerender child components if they are not within the props. But it does because we call myMethod(chart) within the v-for, and that method returns an array/object. 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-for="(chart, index) in items" :key="index">
      <MyComponent :table="myMethod(chart)" :title="chart.title" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    MyComponent,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      showMenu: false,
      items: [{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    myMethod(item) {
      // Remove [brackets] and it doesn't rerender all children
      return ['processed' + item.value];
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Child

```html
<template>
  <div class="myComponent">
    {{ table }}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['table'],
  beforeUpdate() {
    console.log('I have been rerendered');
  },
};
</script>
<style>
.myComponent {
  width: 10em;
  height: 4em;
  border: solid 2px darkblue;
}
</style>
```

Here's a Stackblitz that reproduces it https://stackblitz.com/edit/r3gg3v-ocvbkh?file=src/MyComponent.vue

I need components not to rerender. And I don't see why they do.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this unnecessary rerendering which is the default behavior try to use [v-memo](https://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices/performance.html#v-memo) directive to rerender the child component unless the `items` property changes :

```html
<div v-for="(chart, index) in items" :key="index" v-memo="[items]">
   <MyComponent :table="myMethod(chart)" :title="chart.title" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Boussadjira. `v-memo` prevents rerender even when there are actual changes that justify the rerender. The problem seems to be that Vue’s reactivity only does shallow comparisons on props, so it assumes changes even if there weren't.

Comment: Also, I'd rather avoid stringifying if there's any other option. working example  https://stackblitz.com/edit/r3gg3v-ls8e4a?file=src/MainContainer.vue

Comment: You're welcome, I understand that you want the app works in this example but without stringifying?

Comment: Exactly. My components receive deep props such as arrays of objects. Vue rerenders all components because it performs a shallow comparison, assuming any unrelated data change may affect the props. Stringify solves it by flattening, but it's inelegant at the least.

Comment: @danielp, I'll try to find a solution since this is interesting, if you get it let me know